# How to rewrite somedomain.com/free/single/result_id to somedomain.com/f/single/result_id

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble getting my head around `rewrite`.

I'm trying to make it so that the URL `somedomain.com/f/single/1` would grab the result from `somedomain.com/free/single/1`

I've tried the following.

```
RewriteRule ^/f$ /free$1 [L]
```

Here is a copy of my existing .htaccess with a suggestion made by Kamil...

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^f/(.+)$ /free/$1 [L]
```

I wonder if the problem is that I am already removing index.php before the /free ?

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You look for following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^f/(.+)$ /free/$1 [L]
```

The first part `^f/(.+)$` is [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) - it matches all strings starting with `/f/` and stores the rest to the `$1`... then it's rewritten to `/free/` and the rest stored in `$1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, allthough it still doesnt appear to be working. Here's my full .htaccess file just to make sure theres no conflict?


`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/f/(.+)$ /free/$1 [L]`

If I go to somedomain.com/free/single/1 it works, however somedomain.com/f/single/1 returns a 404

Comment: My mistake - I took your part of the regular expression and didn't realize it. It shouldn't start with the `/` - see updated answer

Comment: Weird, still the same issue. Thanks again for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MartinHunt there has to be some other rules/config preventing the above to work. Pls. update your question with quotation of your configuration.

Comment: @MartinHunt you should put the new rule *before* your current setup (the rule rewriting to index.php)

Comment: I think I've just realised what could be messing with it. I should have mentioned that this is a codeigniter application so the index.php is there on every page. The full url if there were no rewrites would be http://domain.com/index.php/free/single/685#signup-inner does that make a difference?